# Differentiablility of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the function: $f(x,y) = xy^{1/2}$

I want to check what the parital derivatives are at the origin and whether it is differentiable at the origin.

For the partial derivatives at the origin I obtained:

$f_x = y^{1/2} = 0$

$f_y = \frac{1}{2}x y^{-1/2}=0$

Please let me know if these are correct.

Where I'm struggling is showing whether the function is differentiable or not. One idea I have is to say that since $xy^{1/2}$ is a composition of two differentiable functions, it too must be differentiable. However, I'm not sure if this is correct in this case and if it is enough to prove differentiability.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your function is not defined any neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: So it isn't differentiable at the origin?

Comment: Differentiabilty (and even continuity) requires that the function is defined in some neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ok, and how do I show that it isn't defined in some neighborhood of $(0,0)$ is that what the partial derivatives showed since they were both $0$?

Comment: @CharlieP The partial derivatives were not both $0$ - see my answer

Comment: @CharlieP If the partial derivatives were both actually zero then that would be fine - it would indicate that the surface of the function would be flat at the origin

Comment: Kavi is saying that since you haven't declared your function to be complex valued, $xy^{1/2}$ makes no sense for negative $y$ (and therefore makes no sense in the neighbourhood of the origin)

Comment: In addtion there is nobranch of $y^{1/2}$ that is continuous in any neighborhood of the origin, so allowing complex values for $f$ also does not help.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so because $y$ cannot be negative the function cannot be differentiable? I think I'm missing the idea you're trying to present and I'm being a bit brainless.

Comment: Yes, they are saying that a function cannot be differentiable on the boundary of its domain. It can only be differentiable in the interior of its domain.

Comment: For a derivative to exist, the function must be approachable from all directions, loosely speaking. Since it is discontinuous for negative $y$, if I approach the origin from a negative $y$ direction, which *I have to be able to do for the derivative to exist*, I will be met with undefined behaviour and I won't have a derivative

Comment: And if I don't have a derivative from one direction, I cannot claim to have a derivative at all, because the derivative must meet certain criteria

Comment: Ahhhh, ok I get it thanks. I have one more question but I think it's better to ask it in a comment to your Answer since it is related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful and remember the negative power reciprocal laws:

$$f_y=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{y}}=\frac{0}{0}, (x,y)=(0,0).$$

This is *potentially* resolvable using [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), since both $x,y$ go to zero I will treat them as one variable, $u$ - this examines *one* of infinitely many paths of approach to the origin, but by showing that this path fails I show all paths fail (i.e if the limit does not exist for one way, then by definition it cannot exist at all):

$$\frac{d}{du}\frac{u}{2\sqrt{u}}=\frac{d}{du}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$$

Which is undefined at zero and further applications of the law will not help. This shows that there is one path of approaching the origin for which the partial derivative w.r.t $y$ does not exist, showing that it does not exist at the origin in general. For $f$ to be differentiable, we must have that all partial derivatives exist.

I conclude that it is not differentiable at the origin.

Look at these $3$D sketches from Wolfram Alpha of the partial derivative with respect to $y$:
[image: Derivatives]

See how choppy and not well defined they are at $(0,0)$?

Comment: The function is not defined when $y<0$. So the question of differentiabilty or even continuity does not arise.

Comment: @Joe I showed that one path was undefined; this shows the derivative could not exist, if one path of approach did not exist

Comment: Which is what I showed in my post - perhaps I should have been clearer, @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Joe Thank you for spotting the implications of my phrasing - I have edited this now

Comment: So I calculated the partial derivative for $y$ incorrectly? I'm still slightly confused as to what the partial derivative for $y$ is. I thought I'd done it correctly and I checked it on a partial derivative calculator

Comment: You calculated it fine - it's just not possible to evaluate it at $0$. You wrote $\frac{1}{2}xy^{-1/2}$ and I wrote $x/(2\sqrt{y})$ - these are equivalent statements, I was just trying to emphasise the "division by zero" aspect

Comment: Ohhh, ok I understand. Thanks a lot, very helpful

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @CharlieP, so not only can you not take the derivative at the origin, since that is on the boundary of the domain, but the other error you had was evaluating $xy^{-1/2} = 0$ at $(0,0)$. A variable to a non-positive power isn't defined at zero.